# Getting an error TypeError: describe is not a function

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nodejs, mocha

I started creating a base test case using Mocha and Selenium Webriver. I get the following error when I try and run

```
> mocha test

TypeError: describe is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<username>/projects/selenium-testing/test/website_test.js:6:5)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:253:27
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:250:14)
```

My code sample:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
{describe, before, after, it} = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
By = webdriver.by,
until = webdriver.until;

describe('scenarios', function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    driver.get('http://google.com');
  });

  afterEach(function(){
    driver.quit();
  });

  it('find google', function(){

  });

});
```

I am not sure how to take care of this error since I tried all 
1) globally and locally installing selenium-webdriver

Comment: Have you installed mocha?

Answer (score 2):

```
   var Page = require ('../lib/home_page.js');
   var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
  { describe , before , after , it }  require('selenium-webdriver/testing');

    var page;
   describe('library app scenarious', function() {
      beforeEach(function(){
          page = new Page();
          page.CheckOut();
      });

      afterEach(function(){
          page.quit();
      });

      it('Test1',function(){
        console.log('1testpass');
      });

      it('Test2',function(){
        console.log('2testpass');
      })
    });
```

Comment: Yep!!!! I finaly fix this . Just try to init comands (dscribe,before,after,it) in this way(without euqals). I missunderstood how does it work, but it helps me

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is not an issue with Selenium webdriver, it is a part of mocha that might be causing error. please look at it and that should solve

Comment: More explanation on why you think this might be the issue might make this a useful answer. This would fit better as a comment, TBH. Have a look here: [how to answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mocha globally.

> $ npm install --global mocha